# How can I get Ubuntu to set up my printer?

Tags: ubuntu, printing, hp

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and an HP Envy 7800 All-In-One printer which was working fine before I moved. Now, in my new place, the computer recognizes the printer via the WiFi connection, but it will not print. I think it's not set up. I have tried the HP-suggested procedures to no avail.

I believe there are terminal commands which will fix this but don't know what they are. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

From the command line,

`lpstat -t`

will show the total state of the printing system.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions from several people. I discovered that even though I thought my printer had access to the wifi because the computer recognized it, this was not the case. I realized that I had not given the printer the password for wifi access. When I did, the problems disappeared and now my printer is working.I guess the moral is never to trust what you think the hardware knows. Thanks again for the help which indirectly led me to the solution.

Comment: Hi Jim! You should probably mark your own answer as the accepted answer, then :)! That helps future readers, and takes one question out of the list of "unsolved mysteries".